# NotFoundHttpException: GET http://localhost/assortments/1/items when running test

Tags: php, laravel

I have written a test in Laravel. Yet when I run the test it says:

`Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: GET http://localhost/assortments/1/items`

The test I have written:

```
public function testUserCanSeeAllHisItems() {

        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        $user = $this->signIn();

        $itemCreate = Item::factory()->create(['user_id' => $user->id]);
        $assortmentId = $itemCreate->assortment()->first()->id;

        $response = $this->get("/assortments/{$assortmentId}/items");

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

I have tried to google the error but I did not find much. Could the problem be in my routes?

Web.php

```
Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController')->middleware('auth');
Route::resource('assortments/{assortment}/items', 'ItemController')->middleware('auth');
Route::resource('assortments', 'AssortmentController')->middleware('auth');
```

**Edit:**

I also tried the following:

`Route::resource('assortments.items','ItemController')->middleware('auth');`

I also tried `php artisan route:list` and this gives:

`/app/Http/Controllers/CategoryController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route definition is wrong.

```
Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController')->middleware('auth');

// Wrong definition
Route::resource('assortments/{assortment}/items', 'ItemController')->middleware('auth');

// Correct definition
Route::resource('assortments.items', 'ItemController')->middleware('auth');

Route::resource('assortments', 'AssortmentController')->middleware('auth');
```

See this link for more details; https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-nested-resources

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer I tried the correct definition but it still gives the same error.

Comment: Try `php artisan route:list` and post it on your question, please.

Comment: Hi, I posted it in my question. Please check the edit

Comment: `php artisan route:list` causes error. This means your laravel app is not working correctly. Seems like we need a runtime debugging.

Comment: The error is caused because I deleted the category controller, model, migration and view along with the tests because it was not needed anymore. Somewhere it is still included...

Comment: Delete the line `Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController')->middleware('auth');`  and try `php artisan route:list` again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223012/discussion-between-elektakode-and-parsa-237).